# How to lock VBA Project in C#?

Tags: c#, vba, office-interop

I'm using following code to Insert Module in Excel file.
Now i want to "Lock the VBA Project for viewing" using C# but can't find any way.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using VBProject = Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.VBProject;

//Some Other Codes//
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
xlWorkBook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import(@AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Module1.Bas");
```

Comment: At work so don't have time to research a C# method but this helped me do the same in VBA using Win API methods:http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?755909-Excel-Unlock-VBA-Project-Programmatically-using-API

Comment: Thanks for replying but the methods presented in this thread are regarding how to "Unlock" VBA project, while what i'm trying is how to "Lock" the VBA project.

Comment: You might want to have a second look because it should be possible to take the code provieded in the link above, modify it and use it to lock a VBA project.

Answer (score 0):

you cant set programmatically a password :  [See HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office2000/aa165442(v=office.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

"There is no way to programmatically specify a password for a locked VBA project. " which says we cannot set a password through code, but we can check programatically whether a particular vba project is locked or not.

After if you want to set a password with C#, use an automate which sends key to the right window.

[A sample HERE](http://www.nullskull.com/q/10052449/set-excel-vba-project-to-be-password-protected-using-c.aspx)